# Simplifying expression involving Trignometric functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Mathematica is not simplifying the following function. I have tried `TrigExpand`, `FullSimplify`, etc. Nothing is working.

```
1/Sqrt[2 π]
   Cos[π/4 - Sqrt[2] x γ Sin[θ] + 
     Sqrt[2] y δ Sin[θ] + 
     1/2 γ^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
     1/2 δ^2 Sin[2 θ]] Cosh[
    x^2/2 + y^2/2 - Sqrt[2] x γ Cos[θ] + 
     Sqrt[2] y δ Cos[θ] + 
     1/2 γ^2 Cos[2 θ] + 1/2 δ^2 Cos[2 θ] +
      Subscript[p, γ]/2 + Subscript[p, -δ]/2] + 
 1/Sqrt[2 π]
   Cos[π/4 - Sqrt[2] x γ Sin[θ] + 
     Sqrt[2] y δ Sin[θ] - 
     1/2 γ^2 Sin[2 θ] - 
     1/2 δ^2 Sin[2 θ]] Cosh[
    x^2/2 + y^2/2 + Sqrt[2] x γ Cos[θ] - 
     Sqrt[2] y δ Cos[θ] + 
     1/2 γ^2 Cos[2 θ] + 1/2 δ^2 Cos[2 θ] +
      Subscript[p, -γ]/2 + Subscript[p, δ]/2] - 
 1/Sqrt[2 π]
   Cos[π/4 - Sqrt[2] x γ Sin[θ] + 
     Sqrt[2] y δ Sin[θ] + 
     1/2 γ^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
     1/2 δ^2 Sin[2 θ]] Sinh[
    x^2/2 + y^2/2 - Sqrt[2] x γ Cos[θ] + 
     Sqrt[2] y δ Cos[θ] + 
     1/2 γ^2 Cos[2 θ] + 1/2 δ^2 Cos[2 θ] +
      Subscript[p, γ]/2 + Subscript[p, -δ]/2] - 
 1/Sqrt[2 π]
   Cos[π/4 - Sqrt[2] x γ Sin[θ] + 
    Sqrt[2] y δ Sin[θ] - 
    1/2 γ^2 Sin[2 θ] - 
    1/2 δ^2 Sin[2 θ]] Sinh[
   x^2/2 + y^2/2 + Sqrt[2] x γ Cos[θ] - 
    Sqrt[2] y δ Cos[θ] + 
    1/2 γ^2 Cos[2 θ] + 1/2 δ^2 Cos[2 θ] + 
    Subscript[p, -γ]/2 + Subscript[p, δ]/2]
```

Comment: Do you think, anyone likes to type the whole formula in his notebook? Please give it as Mathematica-code, not as LATEx, so we can copy and paste it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Its edited now.

Comment: What if any constraints are there on the parameters/variables? Are any real? Positive? Bounded?

Comment: Please edit your expression, I assume it should be one expression! `TrigExpand` simplifies the modified  expression!

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would not expect that this expression can be transformed into a very-very short one. However, it can be made somewhat compacter. You should help Mma. The final result depends on the answer, in what form do you want to see your result. I show below a few transformations that you might like or dislike depending on your expectation of the resulting form.

Let `expr` be your expression given above. Let us redefine the terms with the subscripts, since the subscripts can influence the simplifications:

```
expr1=expr/.{Subscript[p, -\[Gamma]] -> p\[Gamma]2, 
 Subscript[p, \[Gamma]] -> p\[Gamma]1, 
 Subscript[p, \[Delta]] -> p\[Delta]1, 
 Subscript[p, -\[Delta]] -> p\[Delta]2};
```

Now let us observe that this expression consists of a sum of several heavy terms and let us try to simplify them separately:

```
Map[Simplify, expr1]
```

Evaluate and have a look at the output, while to make it visible here I will put its image

[image]

Maybe, you would like to expand the result such that all trigonometric functions depend on `theta`, rather than on `2theta`?  Then

```
 Map[TrigExpand, expr1, {3}]
```

yielding the following expression

[image]

You might like to transform the expression within the hyperbolic functions into the exponential form:

```
Map[Simplify[TrigToExp[#]] &, expr, {3}]
```

[image]

I hope that helps.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I can come up with is

```
(1/(E^((1/2)*(x^2 + y^2))*(2*Sqrt[Pi])))*((Cos[(Sqrt[2]*(x*γ - y*δ) - 
(γ^2 + δ^2)*Cos[θ])*Sin[θ]] + Sin[(Sqrt[2]*(x*γ - 
y*δ) - (γ^2 + δ^2)*Cos[θ])*Sin[θ]])*
E^(Sqrt[2]*(x*γ - y*δ)*Cos[θ] - (1/2)*(γ^2 + δ^2)*
Cos[2*θ] - (1/2)*(Subscript[p, γ] + Subscript[p, -δ])) + 
(Cos[(Sqrt[2]*(x*γ - y*δ) + (γ^2 + δ^2)*
Cos[θ])*Sin[θ]] + Sin[(Sqrt[2]*(x*γ - y*δ) + 
(γ^2 + δ^2)*Cos[θ])*Sin[θ]])*E^((-Sqrt[2])*(x*γ - 
y*δ)*Cos[θ] - (1/2)*(γ^2 + δ^2)*Cos[2*θ] -
(1/2)*(Subscript[p, -γ] + Subscript[p, δ])))
```